# ArrayList Grouping By specific conditions

Tags: json, spring-boot, java-8, grouping

I have these POJO

```
class LocaleBook
{
  private String bookId;

  private String bookName;

  private Locale locale;
  //setters & getters
}

class Locale
{
  private String country;

  private String language;
  //setters & getters
}
```

Sample data for the above is

```
"alice", "Alice in the wonderland", "GB", "en"
"matrix", "The Matrix", "TH", "en"
"christtree", "The Christmas Tree", "GB", "en"
```

And this method:

```
List<LocaleBook> localeBooks = repo.getLocalBooks();
```

I want to group data together by country and language and i created this POJO:

```
class NewPoJo
{
  private String country;

  private String language;

  private List<KeyValuePair> localeBooks = new HashSet<>();
  //setters & getters
}

class KeyValuePair {

    private String label;

    private String value;
    //setters & getters
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
   {
      "country":"GB",
      "language":"en",
      "localeBooks":[
         {
            "label":"alice",
            "value":"Alice in the wonderland"
         },
         {
            "label":"christtree",
            "value":"The Christmas Tree"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "country":"TH",
      "language":"en",
      "localeBooks":[
         {
            "label":"matrix",
            "value":"The Matrix"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried `Collectors.groupingBy` by `country` and `language` but seems like it will create something like following which is not i want. How can i make it to the expected output i want?

```
{
 "GB_en": [
     {
       "label": "alice"
       "value": "Alice in the wonderland" 
     },
     {
       "label": "christtree"
       "value": "The Christmas Tree" 
     }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by `toMap` collector with `merge` function:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(LocaleBook::getLocale,
                    lb -> new NewPoJo(lb.getLocale().getCountry(), lb.getLocale().getLanguage(),
  new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(new KeyValuePair(lb.getBookId(), lb.getBookName())))),
            (a, b) -> {
                a.getLocaleBooks().addAll(b.getLocaleBooks());
                return a;
            }))
     .values();
```

just you should override `equals` and `hashCode` methods in the `Locale` class.